# How can ı constraint nifi processors response ? (queue) Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]

When I request an API in Nifi, more than one response returns. And the content of these responses is the same. If I don't stop the processor, it keeps coming. I keep turning the processor on and off quickly. Is there a way to restrict this?
Can I have the API return a certain number of times no matter how many requests it sends? For example, return only 3 requests.

Comment: You have a strange requirement. If you want 3 responses then make 3 requests.. if you need to filter out some responses then make clear logic how you want to do it. Return only 3 - in a month or maybe a year?

Comment: @daggett For example, I want 3 responses. I press start from the processor and then I stop. I throw sometimes 3 sometimes 5 requests in the time it takes until I stop it. I can't restrict this from the processor.
If I used a programming language and made a request, I could determine how many requests I would make there.

Comment: Use GenerateFlowfile before invokehttp, set batch size to 3 and schedule to quite rare execution (once per day for example)

Answer (score 3):

NiFi flows are intended to be always-on streams. If you go to the Scheduling tab of a processor's config, you'll see that, by default, it is scheduled to run continuously (0 ms).

If you don't want this style of streaming behaviour, you need to change the Scheduling of the processor.

You can change it to only schedule the processor every X seconds, or you can change it to run based on a CRON expression.